# Using SqlServer Geometry type with IGeometry

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

We have a Fluent Nhibernate model which will connect to an MS Sql Server 2008 database and we've been running unit tests against an SQLite test database.

We are using GeoAPI.Geometries to allow us to have IGeometry members in our class.
When running against the SQLite in-memory test database it goes via a conversion we have add as a convention to our fluent congfiguration.:

```
public class SQLiteGeometryTypeConvention : IPropertyConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
        {
            if (instance.Property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(IGeometry)))
            {
                instance.CustomType(typeof(SQLiteGeometryType));
            }
        }
    }
```

this is using a type we created against the GeometryTypeBase (NHibernate.Spatial.Type) and it works fine for our tests.

When running against the SqlServer we're trying against NHibernate.Spatial.Type.MsSql2008GeometryType:

```
public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
        {
            if (instance.Property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(IGeometry)))
            {
                instance.CustomType(typeof(MsSql2008GeometryType));
            }
        }
```

but this results in the property being returned as null.

Any suggestions about what I should doing? Is it not possible to cast that type against IGeometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/dorony/2010/05/26/easy-testing-of-nhibernatespatial-code/) I originally got the Sqlite code from I actually used the same 
code for the Sql Server type.

I re-wrote the SQL Server bit as:

```
public class MsSqlGeometryConversion : IPropertyConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
        {
            if (instance.Property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(IGeometry)))
            {
                instance.CustomType(typeof(MsSqlGeometryHandler));
            }
        }
    }

    public class MsSqlGeometryHandler : GeometryTypeBase<string>
    {
        public MsSqlGeometryHandler()
            : base(NHibernateUtil.String)
        {
        }

        protected override string FromGeometry(object value)
        {
            return value != null ? ((IGeometry)value).AsText() : null;
        }

        protected override IGeometry ToGeometry(object value)
        {
            return value != null ? new WKTReader().Read((string)value) : null;
        }
    }
```

Which seems to work fine.